# How to Return JSON array to JQUERY alert in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I want JSON to return value is an array with Alert
Currently only returns the ID But need Array From Table Record.
I have table categry with 2 column: ID ,Category.I'm gonna give both displays
my controller:

```
public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
  try {
        $category = Category::create($request->all())->id;
        return response()->json(['id'=>$category]);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'error'));
   }
}
```

my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
data: data,
success: function (data) {
   alert(data.id);
},
error: function () {
   alert(data.err);
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you get on var_dump($category) ??

Comment: I have table categry with 2 column: ID ,Category.I'm gonna give both displays

Comment: What do you want to display exactly in your alert? And what is the version of your Laravel installation?

Comment: Not just any kind of alert can be displayed

Comment: What is your goal? What do you expect exactly?

Comment: I would like to clicking the record button every time a form that can be stored in the database and the table is updated and the new value to be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm note quite sure to fully understand your question, but if you want to return the entire Category record with this controller, you only need to make:

```
public function create(messageRequest $request)
{
  try {
        $category = Category::create($request->all());
        return $category
    }catch (Exception $e){
        return response()->json(array('err'=>'error'));
   }
}
```

You will then be able to access to all your Category data into your ajax callback:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '{!! URL::route('category') !!}',
data: data,
success: function (data) {
   alert('The category I just saved is named ' + data.name + ' and its ID is ' + data.id);
},
error: function () {
   alert(data.err);
  }
});
```

I hope this helps